# Jackson xml module: deserializing immutable type with a @JacksonXmlText property

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I want to serialize an immutable type both as json and as xml:

The serialized JSON is like:

```json
{
    "text" : "... the text..."
}
```

and the serialized xml is like:

```xml
 <asText>_text_</asText>
```

*(note that the text is the xml's element text)*

The java object is like:

```java
@JsonRootName("asText")
@Accessors(prefix="_")
public static class AsText {

    @JsonProperty("text") @JacksonXmlText
    @Getter private final String _text;

    public AsText(@JsonProperty("text") final String text) {
        _text = text;
    }
}
```

beware that the _text property is **final** (so the object is immutable) and it's annotated with `@JacksonXmlText` in order to be serialized as the xml element's text

Being the object immutable, a constructor from the text is needed and the constructor's argument must be annotated with `@JsonProperty`

```java
    public AsText(@JsonProperty("text") final String text) {
        _text = text;
    }
```

When serializing / deserializing to/from JSON everything works fine
... the problem arises when serializing / deserializing to/from XML:

```java
 // create the object
 AsText obj = new AsText("_text_");

 // init the mapper
 XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();

 // write as xml
 String xml = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
 log.warn("Serialized Xml\n{}",xml);

 // Read from xml
 log.warn("Read from Xml:");
 AsText objReadedFromXml = mapper.readValue(xml,
                                              AsText.class);
 log.warn("Obj readed from serialized xml: {}",
          objReadedFromXml.getClass().getName());
```

The exception is:

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "" (class r01f.types.url.UrlQueryStringParam), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "value", "name"])
```

It seems that the xml module needs the object's constructor to be annotated like:

```java
    public AsText(@JsonProperty("") final String text) {
        _text = text;
    }
```

BUT this does NOT even works:

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `test.types.SerializeAsXmlElementTextTest$AsText` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

The annotation `@JsonProperty("text")` at the constructor's argument is needed to deserialize from JSON

... how can i make this to work

Comment: Updated my answer, it does not require a getter. Does that work?

Comment: I'm looking for exactly the same thing if it comes to the xml deserialization. As far as I can see it is not possible unless you change your xml structure like `<asText><text>_text_</text></asText>` as mentioned by @SergGr.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a public getter for the property. I believe that should fix the deserialization issue.

```
@JsonRootName("asText")
@Accessors(prefix = "_")
public static class AsText {

    @JsonProperty("text")
    @JacksonXmlText
    @Getter
    private final String _text;

    public AsText(@JsonProperty("text") final String text) {
        _text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return _text;
    }
}
```

Actually, it works without adding a getter too, with these versions of Lombak & Jackson.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.18</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thank you @Arul, the property already have a getter since lombok is used to "auto-generate" the getter property (beware the `@Getter` annotation)

I'll try to see if it works with a "coded" getter instead of the lombok one

Comment: Sure, np! I did see the annotation from Lombak. I believe Jackson requires a public getter for deserialization in this case.

Comment: @ArulDhesiaseelan, with an explicit getter it does work in term that it compiles and runs, but the output format is different than requested: `<asText><text>_text_</text></asText>` instead of `<asText>_text_</asText>` and I don't think that this is what OP needs. (In this modified format it is easier for Jackson to match text with constructor parameter)

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue with error "no delegate- or property-based Creator". In my case it was problem with Immutables version 2.5.6. I have fixed it by downgrade to version 2.5.5. Version 2.5.6 is available in mvnrepository.com but on official page is as stable version marked 2.5.5.

Comment: Thanks @Jaroslav! I'm using jackson 2.9.0; switching to 2.5.5 is not a viable option for us but I'll give it a try just to see if it's bug of jackson in versions from 2.5.5

Comment: Oh, my fault. I thought that you are using Immutables. But you are using Lombok. And versions I mentioned was related to Immutables. So no need to try downgrade Jackson. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2018**

This hack worked in 2.9.0 but it seems to stop working after this [commit](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/commit/5ad1371036588add77765fd0dc4eaabf85ae2c75). It is not clear if there is an easy way to make it work again.

---

It looks like the main reason for your issue is that you try to use JSON and XML serialization at the same time but with different configurations. Unfortunately `XmlMapper` inherits from `ObjectMapper` and inherits all the JSON-specific configuration (and you can override it but can not clear it with XML-specific annotations) which is the reason for your conflict. It seems that the simplest way to work this around is to use [`@JsonAlias`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html) annotation in the constructor. It is a bit hacky but it works. Here is a minimal example (without Lombok) that works for me:

```
@JsonRootName("asText")
public static class AsText {

    @JsonProperty("text")
    @JacksonXmlText
    private final String _text;

    public AsText(@JsonAlias("") @JsonProperty("text") final String text) {
        _text = text;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getText() {
        return _text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AsText{" +
                "_text='" + _text + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Note that I also added `@JsonIgnore` to the getter because else I didn't get XML format you requested (and you can do the same using Lombok's `onMethod` as described at [onX](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX)).

For a simple test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // create the object
    AsText obj = new AsText("123_text_");

    // init the mapper
    //ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();

    // write as xml
    String xml = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    System.out.println("Serialized Xml\n" + xml);

    // Read from xml
    AsText objReadedFromXml = mapper.readValue(xml, AsText.class);
    System.out.println("Read from Xml: " + objReadedFromXml);
}
```

I get the following output:

> Serialized Xml
>   
>  <asText>123_text_</asText>
>   
>  Read from Xml: AsText{_text='123_text_'}

Comment: What version did you try this on? Copying your code verbatim (no Lombok), deserialization throws `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid definition for property \`\` (of type \`test.AsText\`): Could not find creator property with name '' (known Creator properties: [text])
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 1]` with `jackson-dataformat-xml:2.9.4`

Comment: @TWiStErRob, it was a hack and it worked in **2.9.0** but it seems that it stopped working after this [commit](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/commit/5ad1371036588add77765fd0dc4eaabf85ae2c75). I'm not sure if there is an easy way to make this hack work again.